# match whitespace ignoring before of cursor

Tags: vim, match, highlighting

For show the whitespaces in the end of line I use this `hi`

```
highlight whitespaceEOL term=reverse ctermbg=Grey  guibg=Grey
match whitespaceEOL /\s\+$/
```

but when I when I write, mark the whitespace before of cursor.
how I can ignore this match ?

PD: I know `\%#` (cursor-position), but how integrate in the match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match whitespaceEOL /\s\+\(\%#\)\@!$/
```